# "Input string was not in a correct format" error when trying to display hour portion with 'h'

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

I am trying to display a datetime field using the hour portion only without leading zeros for the single digit hours as in:  `return string.Format("{0:h}", MyDateTimefield)` but I get a "Input string was not in a correct format" error. Why?

`return string.Format("{0:hh}", MyDateTimefield)` works. Looking for the correct format and not a workaround.

Comment: Is the MyDateTimefield of type `DateTime`? I ask because if it is, you could probably just return `MyDateTimefield.ToString("h");`

Comment: @pstrjds that throws the same error.

Comment: I know you don't want a workaround, but MyDateTimefield.Hour.ToString() will work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [the pertinent docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hSpecifier):

> If the "h" format specifier is used without other custom format specifiers, it is interpreted as a standard date and time format specifier and throws a FormatException. For more information about using a single format specifier, see [Using Single Custom Format Specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers) later in this topic.

Following that link gets you to:

> To use any of the custom date and time format specifiers as the only specifier in a format string […], include a space before or after the specifier, or include a percent ("%") format specifier before the single custom date and time specifier.

Comment: I used two different format string cheatsheets and they didn't mention the single format specifiers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From [this link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) using `h` is the correct format for hour without leading 0. Very interesting.. the following all seem to work:

```
return string.Format("{0: h}", MyDateTimefield)
return string.Format("{0:h }", MyDateTimefield)
return string.Format("{0:h:m}", MyDateTimefield)
```

But as soon as you put in `return string.Format("{0:h}", MyDateTimefield)` it throws an exception.

As for why, I'm not sure. If you're okay with a space the first 2 lines should work.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is that apparently, single-character format strings are Special in .NET and are interpreted only as "standard format specifiers".

Comment: Just read your answer. Good find. I was reading through the same msdn page but I seemed to just completely skip that section :)